# How do I place shortcuts from bookmarks onto desktop

Tags: shortcuts

I want to put shortcuts from my bookmarks onto my desktop. I tried to drag and drop from bookmarks to desktop , but it didn't work.

Please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is this really the only way to simply put a link to a web page on my desktop?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/84674/is-this-really-the-only-way-to-simply-put-a-link-to-a-web-page-on-my-desktop)

Answer (score 2):

You can open the "Show all Bookmarks" option in Firefox and drag and drop the bookmark from the dialog to the Desktop

Comment: Thanks Theodotos,  I just installed Ubuntu for the first time last night , looks strange.

Answer (score 0):

I have a very similar question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84674/is-this-really-the-only-way-to-simply-put-a-link-to-a-web-page-on-my-desktop)

I opted to use the firefox add-on mentioned near the end.

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome, click the vertical dots on the right of the toolbar,

mouse-over "Bookmarks"

Select "Bookmark Manager"

navigate to the bookmark you want to move,

click and drag it to the desktop